# Equivalent functional integral of ODEs

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, finite-element-method, variational-analysis

I was going through the Ritz method in Finite Element analysis when I came across the statement [here](https://www.cae.tntech.edu/%7Echriswilson/FEA/ANSYS/ansysfea_chapter_stolarskipdf.pdf) (see equation 1.25, its not same but similar. below I have taken a problem from my book.),

> Consider a Boundary Value Problem in 1-D having a differential equation,$$ \frac{d^2f}{dx^2} =-g(x)$$ for $$a<x<b$$
> The functional equivalent of the above D.E. is written as $$J(f)=\int_a^b \left(\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{df}{dx}\right]^2-f(x)g(x)\right)dx$$Equation above is obtained by intuition, but it is shown to really give
> the functional of the first equation. So, the solution to the differential equation is equivalent to minimizing the above quadratic functional.

What is that intuition that gives such a functional relation for f? Isn't there a definite way to obtain such an integral statement? Can anyone help me with the steps leading this DE to this integral statement?

Answer (score 1):

Without fundamentals, according to the Euler-Lagrange criteria, the stationary points to the functional

$$
J(f) = \int_a^b L(f',f,x)dx
$$

are obtained by solving

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\partial L}{\partial f'}\right)-\frac{\partial L}{\partial f}=0
$$

now calling $L = \frac 12\left(f'\right)^2-f g$ we are done. If the functional $J(f)$ has a minimum, then the Euler-Lagrange criteria gives it.

Comment: Yes I understand you're trying to explain the methods of minimising J(f) but I want to know that why we choose L of the form you've mentioned in the first place?

Comment: The cited text in your question, explains it satisfactorily.

Comment: I don't think so, it simply brushes it off saying it was done by intuition. But what intuition is it that converts a DE into an integral minimizing statement?

Comment: Studying Calculus of Variations we can learn how to determine the stationary functions that minimizes/maximizes a functional. Those solution functions, obey a relationship called the Euler-Lagrange equation. So the minimized/maximized functional is minimized/maximized by the resulting ode from Euler-Lagrange. Thus in those cases, there is equivalent to minimize/maximize the functional and to solve the ode obtained from the Euler-Lagrange criteria.